# change vertical space in matrix after linebreak

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, tikz-matrix

I want to change the vertical space between two lines in a matrix. Normally I could do this with `row sep`, but this doesn't affect the vertical space if the line is breaked, see picture. I tried `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.5}` without success.
What's the right command?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(LH)[row sep=1mm, matrix of nodes, column sep=35mm, text width=54mm] {
& consetetur sadipscing elitr\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  & sed diam nonumy eirmodtempor invidunt ut labore\\
& et dolore magna aliquyam erat,\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(LH)[row sep=1mm, matrix of nodes, column sep=35mm, text width=54mm] {
& consetetur sadipscing elitr\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  & sed\vspace{3cm} diam nonumy eirmodtempor invidunt ut labore\\
& et dolore magna aliquyam erat,\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```